# Elder Sign - locked dice queries

Tags: elder-sign

First query - can I take the locked dice from a resolved monster and use it right away to complete the rest of the adventure card it was on?

Second - if I have a locked red dice on one card or monster then draw another card or monster with a locked red dice symbol, do I have to wait to clear the red dice from the first and move it to the second before I can try and resolve the second adventure, so the second card is basically out of play until the first lock is resolved? Or can I try and clear the second card to stop the lock moving?

Comment: Welcome to Board and Card games Q&A. Can you please move the second question to a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Locked dice on monsters are only unlocked when the monster is collected, which happens at the end of the Investigation Phase. Note that even if you failed to solve the Adventure or Other World card, you will still collect the monster trophy as long as you completed that task. You can then use the unlocked die on your next attempt.

Adventure cards can be done in any order, even if there are multiple locks active at the same time. The physical location of the locked die doesn't really matter. If you complete a card with a locked die on it the die moves to another lock if there is one, or if there wasn't a die on the card it stays locked on the card where it is. Whether it moves or not is irrelevant; you will need to remove both locks before you can use that die again.